# Does iOS AWS Mobile Hub supports Cognito Sync and how?

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I guess my question is two fold:

1. Does AWS mobile hub supports cognito sync?  I have downloaded and
   looked into their sample app but I can only see the sign in part
2. If yes, how do I get a "dataset"?  The user pool created by mobile hub
   doesn't even have "identity browser" said on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-console.html)

If I use mobile hub to login, can I pod AWSCognito myself and use cognito sync?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Hub does support Cognito sync. You can demo this feature by enabling the User Data Storage feature in your Mobile Hub project, then downloading the sample app.

The User Data Storage feature will also integrate with the Sign In feature if it is enabled in your project.

To retrieve the Cognito dataset, see the example inside the sample application (folder: Demo > UserSettings) or you can explicitly do the following:

```
let syncClient: AWSCognito = AWSCognito.default()
let userSettings: AWSCognitoDataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("user_settings")
userSettings.setString(<value>, forKey: <key>)
userSettings.synchronize()
```

There are also platform specific instructions in the integrate page of your Mobile Hub project.

Comment: Working through the same issue, your answer is similar to as far as I've gotten, but I can't get the AWSCognito to setup properly, especially without having to create new credentials providers and enter in the region and ids manually. Even when I do that, I get errors back "unable to list records".

Regarding adding "user data storage" to the mobile hub project, all I see is "no sql database" and "user file storage". The former seems like it would be the answer, but unfortunately it only seems to want to create new dynamo tables and not link into existing tables or cognito datasets.